# correct way of predicting test data with c5.0 in r

Tags: r

I am fitting the model on train data. Following are my variables

```
Train Variables = Client_Code,A,B,C,D,E,Target
Test Variables = Client_Code,A,B,C,D,E,Target
```

I am training the model with following code

```
model <- c5.0(Target~.,data=train[,-1]) # removing Client_Code
```

Once the model is trained,I am predicting it with following code

```
model_test <- predict(model,test[,-1])
```

Where as my test data also has `Target` column which I am predicting.Is above the correct way of predicting or I have to store the target variable in different variable and then pass it to the model when I train it and same while predicting on the test dataset.

Comment: Is there any reason you think this is wrong? Are you encountering an error or something?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is quite alright to separate the class variable you want to predict. For example for the [credit data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Credit+Approval):

```
library(C50)

# Load data
crx <- read.table( file="./crx.data", header=FALSE, sep="," )

set.seed(1234)
# Randomize data
crx <- crx[ sample( nrow( crx ) ), ]

# Classification data and its labels
X <- crx[,1:15]
y <- crx[,16]

# Divide into training and test data
trainX <- X[1:500,]
trainy <- y[1:500]
testX <- X[501:690,]
testy <- y[501:690]

# Build model
model <- C50::C5.0( trainX, trainy )
summary( model )

# Predicting values
p <- predict( model, testX, type="class" )

# Check accuracy
accuracy <- sum( p == testy ) / length( p )
paste0((accuracy * 100), "% accuracy")
```